# Instagram iOS API Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"

Tags: ios, uiwebview, instagram, instagram-api, uiwebviewdelegate

I am working on a project for iPhone where I have to take images from Instagram. I implemented the following API as mentioned on its developer site:

> https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

When I hit this URL in my `UIWebview` I get the following error:

> Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"

But when I hit the same URL in the device browser it works. But it modifies the URL to be:

> https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&scope=SCOPE

I also tried to put this modified URL in my code. Then it works and asks me to log in. But when I log in I get this error.

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"
}
```

I recently created a client ID and checked all parameters. So I'm not sure what the issue is. I googled it and found that `UIWebView` doesnt allow this. So I put this in `didFinishLaunching` in my `AppDelegate` class:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

But this is also not working. Please advise for any solution regarding this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any help?